# Word for a person with a negative attitude

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What is the person called who always thinks negative? E.g.

> - Mr. X always thinks negative.
> - Mr. X has negative attitude.

What we can use either? Is there any particular word for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The word is ***pessimist***, a person who expects the worst.

> Mr X is a pessimist.

Contrast with ***optimist***.

> It is often said that while optimists are happier, pessimists are more often correct.

and

> Optimists are said to live longer than pessimists, though a pessimist might say those extra few years are bound to be miserable.

Comment: Difference between a pessimist and an optimist.  In difficult situation, the pessimist will say "It can hardly be any worse than that".  The optimist will answer "Of course it can !".

Answer (score 11):

There are a lot of colloquialisms and other terms that mean the same thing:

"Mr. X is a ..."

- Negative Nancy
- Downer
- Drag
- Debbie Downer
- Naysayer
- Prophet of doom
- Doomsayer
- Futilitarian

Comment: +1 for Negative Nancy, which I have heard to describe both men and women.

Comment: I like *futilitarian*. Hadn't heard that before.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatives for consideration:

1. Cynic
2. Defeatist

Answer (score 4):

'Mr X Thinks negatively' is correct.

However, 'Mr X is a pessimist' is more grammatically sound.

Answer (score 1):

I've always enjoyed slang expressions like "Mr Unhappy is a real *[stick in the mud](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stick_in_the_mud)*" (i.e. won't participate) and similar expressions like *curmudgeon* or *party pooper*. They have slightly different connotations than always thinking negatively, but I think the mindset would have the be similar to support them.

Answer (score 0):

A **lackadaisical** person is someone who is listless and lacking vigor or determination, in short someone with a negative attitude.